# The key to my room. Vs The key of my room

Tags: grammar, prepositions, prepositional-phrases, possessives

To.         Vs of

> - I am looking for the key **of** my room.
> - I am looking for the key **to** my room.

I have just known that the second is right and the first is wrong. However, sometimes it is confusing in a lot of situations to discern what the right one is.

Is there any rule in regard to the usage of **to** and **of**, particularly when we want to describe the belongings or possessions of something?!

Do I have to say

> - the damage to my house, or the damage of my house
> - the door to my room, or the door of my room
> - the password to my account, or the password of my account?

Comment: The most natural phrases (to my British English ears) are "I am looking for the key **for** my room", and "the password **for** my account".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have studied four Indo-European languages in addition to my native English. If there are any rules on which prepositions are proper in which situations, they are not easily discerned or explicated in any of those languages. In English, the **predominant** preposition relating to accessibility seems to be "to."

So "door to that room," "key to that lock," and "password to that account" are all idiomatic. However, "door of that room," "key for that lock," and "password for that account" are also idiomatic.

That quasi-rule about "to" being associated with accessibility has no apparent relevance to the phrase "damage to," but "to" is idiomatic although **sometimes** "damage in" will be idiomatic.

EDIT: Although "the key of that lock" does not sound euphonius, "that lock's key" sounds perfectly natural. Prepositions are weird.

Comment: "the key of that lock" is euphonious enough if the emphasis is on *that*, as compared with "the key of *this* lock". But it does seem to need emphasis on *one* of the words "key", "that" or "lock" - it doesn't sound right as a "neutral" reference to the object in question.

Comment: @alephzero Agreed. It is like many things in English: exceptions abound. But the primary points that I wanted to make were that: (a) "to" **is** idiomatic in all the examples given, (b) sometimes more than one preposition will work, and (c) usage of prepositions is not subject to clear-cut rules.

Comment: I wouldn't consider "door of that room" to be idiomatic.

Comment: "The door of the room suddenly blew open"  is not idiomatic?

Comment: +1 for a most intelligent answer, defying those who seek rules for everything as did Professor Grammar on the BBC World Service years ago.

Comment: It sounds extremely convincing. Can we, though, say that the Preposition phrases memorization through context is the key to master English prepositions usage?

Comment: @BavyanYaldo That is a question that I am not competent to answer definitively. I suspect that what method or methods are most effective will depend in part on the native language of the learner. I suppose some rules for the choice of English prepositions could be framed so long as it was repeatedly stressed that the rules will be riddled with exceptions. Ultimately, a lot of language learning does come down to brute memorization. Sorry to be so vague about methods of teaching.

Answer (score 8):

The choice of **to** or **of** is largely governed by idiom and will vary according to the context. More often than not, native English speakers will refer to **the key to** the safe, the door, the house, resolving a problem and much else.

It's idiomatic. In fact, in most cases, they will simply say **the room/safe/door key** but that's not what you are asking about.

**The key of** my room is acceptable but less likely than **the key to my room**.
And the same is true for **the door** and **the password**. Damage is definitely **to** something and NOT **of** something.

Google Books Ngram Viewer indicates that while the expression **the key of** was twice as popular as **the key to** in the first half of the 19th century, **the key to** subsequently prevailed and is now about six times as common as **the key of**.

It's hard to make a rule but as a guide, prefer **the key to** as the safer option in most instances.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+key+to%2Cthe+key+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20key%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20key%20of%3B%2Cc0